# Exporting the same android app without overwriting existing on phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm about to export a few different changes done to my app, but I want it to export as another standalone application, but from the same project in Eclipse.

How do I export it so that it won't overwrite the other application I have? Do I need to create a new project and do it that way, or can I just make some changes to the existing in order for it to export a new standalone app?

If I'm not clear enough, I'll elaborate more.

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix I found was to just copy and paste the project, but change the package name from (example) com.example.app to com.example.branchofapp.app.

On refactoring from Eclipse all I had to do was review the changes, and change some settings in the manifest file to recognize the package name.

The refactoring tool in Eclipse also told me that this will create a "same-but-different" application on the phone, so you can have the same application installed as many times as you want, as long as the package name is different as well.

I understand that my need is probably a little too much for such small changes, but the idea behind the development of my app requires me to do it this way (as it's only for showing possible customers).

Answer (score 0):

One eclipse project can generate only one app at a time.The name and the version can be controlled from manifest file.
Please provide more clarity what you want to do

Comment: When I export the existing project with some changes made to the manifest file, the name of the app changes, everything is up to date in relations to that, but once I install the app on the development phone, it overwrites the old application and replaces it with the new one instead of installing the app so that it lies on the phone together with the old app.